# Parametrizing a rose-like curve

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates, parametrization

What is a parametrization for the following curve?

[image]

Maybe I can slightly alter the following parametrization in polar coordinates: $(\sin(3\theta),\theta)$ for $\theta\in [0,\pi]$ which gives:

[image]

to obtain the parametrization I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [trefoil knot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot) which Wikipedia states that the parametrization is as follows:

$$x=\sin t + 2\sin 2t$$
$$y=\cos t - 2\cos 2t$$

Where $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. You can flip the graph upside down by multiplying both the $x$ and $y$ by $-1$, and you scale it by changing the coefficients of the trigonometric functions.

Judging by the picture in your question, [this parametrization fits well](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+(x%3D1.5sin(t)-2sin(2t),+y%3D1.5cos(t)%2B2cos(2t))), thanks [WaveX!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668583/parametrizing-a-rose/2668591#comment5512233_2668591)

$$x=-1.5\sin t - 2\sin 2t$$
$$y=-1.5\cos t + 2\cos 2t$$

Comment: Scaling the $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ by $1.5$ gives a close to [exact match](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+(x%3D1.5sin(t)-2sin(2t),+y%3D1.5cos(t)%2B2cos(2t))) on WolframAlpha to what the OP wanted, after flipping the graph upside down. +1